# creating a symlink for strings.xml in values folder

Tags: android

In Android Studio I wanted to reutilize the values-id folder's strings.xml file into the values-in folder. So I created a strings.xml file and added a symlink for the values-in folder.

```
../values-id/strings.xml
```

Because of this, I am not able to build the workspace. Getting an error: **Top level element is not completed** is there any way to symlink a values folder instead of rewriting?

Answer (score 3):

I am using symlinks in my project for gradle files and source folders.

In case of Mac OS:

```
ln -s relative/source/path destination/folder
```

In case of Windows:

```
mklink /j destination\folder relative\source\path
```

Provided example works for folders. Tested on Android studio since v1.4.
One thing that is not convenient that you getting some mess with Git.

Comment: I need it for Android Studio and Android, not on PC

Answer (score 1):

Test on Android Studio 3.3 on Mac

First, you go inside the folder, where you want to use the symlink path

```
 cd `<folder path where you want to add classes>`
```

run this command of which you want to create a symlink

```
ln -s `<relative path of classes from this folder>`
```